# Suppose we flipped 3 coins simultaneously, till we get the first head, what would be the mean number of tosses(including the last one)?

Tags: probability, statistics

I tried to evaluate it by multiplying the probability of each scenario with the number of flips it took to get there but this didn't work, and now I'm really confused, so if someone could provide an answer, I would really appreciate it if they could go into detail.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Could you show us what you tried exactly and why you were confused?

Answer (score 1):

The chance of one of the coins being heads is .875. The mean of a geometric distribution is `1/p` which means it would take on average 1.142857 flips.

Answer (score 1):

We can split it into two parts:

1. Probability of having at least one head when fliping 3 coins
2. When will the first head shows up?

Part 1 is binomial distributed, assume all 3 coins are fair, $p=0.5$
So, $P(at\ least \ one \ head) = 1 - P(all \ tail) = 1-0.5^{3}=0.875$

Part 2 is geometrically distributed, you can find the mean by $\frac{1}{p}$